# LINQ to XML Newbie Question

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an loaded an XML document with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
  <sheetData>
    <row r="1" spans="1:2">
      <c r="A1" t="s">
        <v>0</v>
      </c>
      <c r="B1" t="s">
        <v>1</v>
      </c>
    </row>
  </sheetData>
</worksheet>
```

I want to query the document for any elements named `c` that has the attribute `t = s`.

I have tried many different variations on how to do this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Sheet1.xml");
var rows = from row in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("worksheet").Elements("sheetData")
       select row;
```

But it always returns an empty set.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Root element is the `<worksheet/>` element so asking the root for a worksheet descendant will always return an empty set. Remove the `.Descendants("worksheet")` clause and you should start seeing some results.

Comment: What about `xmlDoc.Root.Elements("sheetData").Elements("row)`?

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work for me either.  I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but the snippet is from a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet converted to XML.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the namespace of the node you are getting with Descendants or Elements.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
var rows = from row in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "sheetData")
       select row;
```

Comment: this caught me out the first time I used Linq to XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Sheet1.xml");
var rows = from row in xmlDoc.Root.Element(ns + "sheetData").Elements(ns + "row")
       select row;
```

This grabs all the "row" elements from within the root/sheetData element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote in [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net) that does the filter on c where t = s.

I know the answer has been accepted, but this solution actually does the filtering whereas none of the other answers above do :)

Hope this helps!

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>
        <worksheet xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"" xmlns:r=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"">
            <sheetData>
                <row r=""1"" spans=""1:2"">
                    <c r=""A1"" t=""s"">
                        <v>0</v>
                    </c>
                    <c r=""A2"" t=""b"">
                        <v>0</v>
                    </c>
                    <c r=""B1"" t=""s"">
                        <v>1</v>
                    </c>
                </row>
            </sheetData>
        </worksheet>";

    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

    var d = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    //d.Dump();
    //d.Dump("xdocument dump");

    var q = from cell in d.Root.Descendants(ns + "sheetData").Descendants(ns + "row").Descendants(ns + "c")
            where cell.Attributes("t").FirstOrDefault().Value == "s"
            select cell;
    q.ToList().Dump();
```

}